# Can std::transform or std::generate without ExecutionPolicy be parallel?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++17

In C++17 parallel std algorithms were introduced (overloads with ExecutionPolicy arguments), where strict rules of execution order, interleaving and paralelization were defined, for example ([algorithm.parallel.exec/3]):

> The invocations of element access functions in parallel algorithms invoked with an execution policy object of
>   type execution::sequenced_policy all occur in the calling thread of execution. [ Note: The invocations are not interleaved; see 4.6. — end note ]

(same thing in [current draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#exec-4))

The problem is that I can't find any such requirement for old, non-parallel overloads of these algorithms.

**Question:** Can this mean that library implementers can, since C++11 when *thread of execution* term was introduced, implement std::transform and std::generate using SIMD/multithreading/other(?)? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: As long as the observable behavior of your program are not changed compilers and library implementation can do anything. I don't think their are implementation using multithreading, because demonstrating that multithreading will not change the observable behavior of your program would be difficult. On the other hand, optimizers usualy generate SIMD instructions. Whatsoever you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Given that you can `std::transform` an InputIterator in the non-parallel overload, but the parallel requires at least ForwardIterator, I think the order of evaluation is fixed.

Comment: @Caleth That fails to convince; std algorithms need not have one implementation, they can tag dispatch based on type of iterator.

Comment: @Caleth An implementation could check at compile time if it has been given a better iterator than required. In theory the standard allows it under the as-if-rule while in practice no standard library implementation will create a thread for standard algorithms unless explicitly required because that unnecessarily allocates global resources which is surprising and bad.

Comment: @nwp but it could have a pool of such threads available and use them.  My concern is if there are any implicit guarantees that the *thread local* variables of any such threading would match the *thread local* state of the calling thread?  Both ways can lead to surprises.

Comment: There's also **[res.on.data.races]/8** "Unless otherwise specified, C++ standard library functions shall perform all operations solely within the current thread if those operations have effects that are visible (4.7) to users." That would appear to preclude any kind of behind-the-scenes multithreading that touches any user-defined entities.

Comment: compilers will not try to create threads implicitly. But they can optimize code with the use of SIMD instructions (for instance, if range size is always a multiple of 4). Also, load/store are usually not implicitly SIMD-optimized because this requires guaranteed memory alignment

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: This looks like the answer I was looking for! : ) Thanks!

Comment: I did not see that part of the library specification to come into play here. God I hate the indirect way in which the library is specified *so much*.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**[res.on.data.races]/8**](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.data.races#8) Unless otherwise specified, C++ standard library functions shall perform all operations solely within the current thread if those operations have effects that are visible (4.7) to users.

This precludes any kind of behind-the-scenes multithreading that touches any user-defined entities.

I suppose, in principle, something like `std::sort` working on a `vector<int>` can prove that no user-defined class is involved, and send work to multiple threads. That's rather far-fetched, it's difficult to imagine any implementation doing this in practice.